# Algorithm for taking elements from an in[] array and concatenating them

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

I need all the elements in an `int[]` array to be concatenated together, but come out as an int instead of a string.
For instance:
I have an array:
`int[] array1 = {1, 2, 7, 16};`
I need to smush all the elements of the array so that the console prints out these numbers as one and saves them to a variable as a SINGLE `int`. So the answer here would be 12716.

Comment: Okay, so you've stated your requirements.... and? What now? Do you expect us to write your code for you?  You have to show some effort, please.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You just answered your own question, Jonathon. I need the algorithm and I couldn't find it anywhere else. I thought it was pretty clear that I wanted somebody to give me a good understanding of how this works.

Comment: Why did so many people downvote this? I was a dumb beginner and I didn't know how to do it. Seriously, what the hell people. This ruined my account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate them together as a string and then parse the string as an `int`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : array1) {
    sb.append(i);
}
int concatenated = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
```

An alternative (and, to my mind, more cumbersome) approach is to initialize a `sum` to 0 and then add each array element after multiplying `sum` by 10 or 100 (or 1000, ...) depending on how big the array element is.